# Why didn't Oracle use the right index?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

This is my first question in stack overflow, thank you for helping me sincerely.

Recently, one of my oracle databases(version: 12c) occurred a weird event: When Oracle processed one frequently used SQL which looked like this :

```
select col_a, col_b, col_c, col_d, ...
from Table_A
where col_a='..' and col_b='..' and col_c='..'
```

it didn't use the right index which was perfectly mapping the where clause: `index_1(col_a, col_b, col_c)`, instead of using another index: `index_2(col_a, col_d)`.

One Oracle expert in my company told me the reason: Table_A was an partitioned table, and I recently added a sql for deleting old partitions which incurred Oracle to recompile sqls relevant to this table. After the deletion of old partitions, total amount of records in Table_A dropped largely, then Oracle SQL compiler calculated the efficiency of two indices: `index_1(col_a, col_b, col_c) and index_2(col_a, col_d),` and found that both indices had almost equal efficiency for processing previously mentioned SQL, so it chose the second index--index_2 which could be seen simpler.

This explanation puzzled me for some days. Could you guys ever experienced this kind of puzzle? Have you found the right answer?

Please tell me, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "deletion of old partitions" etc is not particularly relevant here except in that it means that an existing SQL statement needed to be parsed again. *Any* time you do a hard parse on a SQL statement there is the chance of a new execution plan being evaluated. (Thats a good thing, because if the data distribution has changed, you'd like the database to react accordingly).

A potential cause here is the size of the index.  Here's an artificial example to show how this could happen

```
SQL> create table t ( x int, y int, z char(60) , c char(100));

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> insert into t select mod(rownum,20), rownum, rownum, rownum
  2  from dual
  3  connect by level <= 100000;

100000 rows created.

SQL> exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('','T');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> create index ix1 on t (x,y,z ) ;

Index created.

SQL> create index ix2 on t (x,y);

Index created.

SQL>
SQL> set autotrace traceonly explain
SQL> select * from t
  2  where x=123 and y=123 and z='123';

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 76562274

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                           | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                    |      |     1 |   170 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| T    |     1 |   170 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | IX2  |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("Z"='123')
   2 - access("X"=123 AND "Y"=123)
```

So we used IX2 even through IX1 is the best "match".  This is because whilst IX1 holds all three columns, the 3rd one (Z) is a large character which will bloat out the size of the index, making it slightly more expensive to scan. If I force the use of IX1, I can see that the optimizer costed it slightly higher even though in both cases, it is expecting just a solitary row to come back.

```
SQL>
SQL> select /*+ index(t ix1) */ * from t
  2  where x=123 and y=123 and z='123';

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2932790928

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                           | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                    |      |     1 |   170 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| T    |     1 |   170 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | IX1  |     1 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("X"=123 AND "Y"=123 AND "Z"='123')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I'm not very sure about that I understand your explanation, but I notice that in your answer, the two indices have a relation that one index(ix2) is a subset of another index(ix1). In my circumstance,  the two indices don't have the relation: index_2 contains a column(col_d) which is not included in index_1. Is that make a difference?

Comment: My point was that the optimizer doesn't decide on what columns etc are in (or out ) of the index, ie, there isn't a rules based approach. It looks at all potential access paths and assigns a cost (cpu+I/O) to each of those paths.  Cheapest wins.